# Why is my service worker requesting an insecure page?

Tags: angular, https, service-worker, angular-service-worker

When I view my domain like https://example.com (without the www.) I'm getting the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/ngsw-worker.js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://www.example.com/index.html'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This results in Chrome showing a "This site can't be reached" message.
Why is my service worker trying to request index.html without https?

**Update** I was able to work around it by changing my `ngsw-config.json` to point directly to `https://www.example.com/index.html` instead of `/index.html` which stopped it from trying to fetch it insecurely, but I still don't understand why it was necessary.

Comment: Have you used angular's service worker or are you creating your own?

Comment: @Remy, I am using Angular's service worker. Also, see my update.

Comment: sadly this workaround is not working for localized builds that have exmple.com/en/index.html and example.com/fr/index.html as domain